# Custom script returned array overwrite non-empty cells

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to make a script returning an array of values that will overwrite non-empty cells?
For example: I have a list of tasks with the following fields: 'task-name, estimated time as in '3w'. The 3rd column is calculated with a custom function that translate the '3w' to 3*5=15 (in days). The custom script takes a range and returns an array of results for the given array of estimated-times from the 2nd column.

All works well until I decide to take a row and move it to re-order the list of tasks. Once I move that row, lets say, one row above, the script complains about an error because the moved row contains a non-empty value where it used be automatically computed by the custom-script. To correct it I need to clear the value of that row at the 3rd column and the script returns to calculate as before.

There should be a way to tell the script to overwrite. Is there?

Thanks,
Erez

Answer (score 0):

Use the [isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isBlank%28%29) function to check whether the specified cell in empty and the [clear()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear) function in order to clear the value in the cell and provide a new one. Here is a small sample:

```
function myFunction(){
  var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var range = ss.getDataRange();

  var maxCol = range.getLastColumn();
  var maxRow = range.getLastRow();

  for (var i=0; i<maxRow; i++)
  {
    for (var j=0; j<maxCol; j++)
    {
      if(!ss.getRange(i+1, j+1).isBlank())
      {
        ss.getRange(i+1, j+1).clear();

      }
    }
  }
}
```